# Copying files as fast as possible

Tags: optimization, bash, file-system, linux, network-file-transfer

I am running my shell script on `machineA` which copies the files from `machineB` and `machineC` to `machineA`.

If the file is not there in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC` for sure. So I will try to copy from `machineB` first, if it is not there in `machineB` then I will go to `machineC` to copy the same files.

In `machineB` and `machineC` there will be a folder like this `YYYYMMDD` inside this folder:

```
/data/pe_t1_snapshot
```

Whatever date is the latest date in this format `YYYYMMDD` inside the above folder - I will pick that folder as the full path from where I need to start copying the files.

Suppose, if this is the latest date folder `20140317` inside `/data/pe_t1_snapshot`, then this will be the full path for me:

```
/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140317
```

from where I need to start copying the files in `machineB` and `machineC`. I need to copy around `400` files in `machineA` from `machineB` and `machineC` and each file size is 3.5 GB.

I currently have my below shell script which works fine as I am using scp, but somehow it takes ~3 hours to copy the 400 files in `machineA`.

Below is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly PRIMARY=/export/home/david/dist/primary
readonly SECONDARY=/export/home/david/dist/secondary
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/data/pe_t1_snapshot
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(0 3 5 7 9) # this will have more file numbers around 200
SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1 2 4 6 8) # this will have more file numbers around 200

dir1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]} ls -dt1 "$MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)
dir2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]} ls -dt1 "$MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)

echo $dir1
echo $dir2

if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ]
then
    # delete all the files first
    find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete
    for el in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
    do
        scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
    done

    # delete all the files first
    find "$SECONDARY" -mindepth 1 -delete
    for sl in "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}"
    do
        scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$sl"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/. || scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/t1_weekly_1680_"$sl"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/.
    done
fi
```

I am copying `PRIMARY_PARTITION` files in `PRIMARY` folder and `SECONDARY_PARTITION` files in `SECONDARY` folder in `machineA`.

Is there any way to move the files faster in `machineA`? Can I copy 10 files at a time or 5 files at a time in parallel instead of **downloading all the files in parallel** to speed up this process or any other approach?

**I don't want to download all the files in parallel.** `rsync` is not helping me as well, I tried copying with `rsync` as well. I guess, I need to go multithreaded way, meaning copy 3 files in parallel instead of one file at a time. If those three files are done, then only move to next three files to copy it.

Maybe I only need to run two parallel processes, one downloading from B and one from C. Each process removes a file name from the master list, puts that file name into its own list, and tries to download it. If downloading is unsuccessful, then it puts that file name back onto the master list. The loop then repeats itself again, making sure not to try to download any file if its name is already in its own list. I simply need to run two processes which do this in parallel, one each from machine B and C.

Is this possible to do? If yes, then can anyone provide an example on this? I am trying to limit the number of threads, not have 400 parallel processing.

NOTE: `machineA` is running on SSD and has 10 gig ethernet.

Comment: I would expect network bandwidth to be the bottleneck here. If packets from both B and C travel through the same pipe, you're unlikely to gain anything by running in parallel. Can you describe the network topology a little?

Comment: @DavidHarkness: As far as I know, we have 10 gig network. I am not a unix guy, so not sure what other information you might need? if you can ask me specifically, then I might be able to answer or I can check with our unix admin.

Comment: Are these machines all on the same local network? Of course, compressing the files first may shave quite a bit of time if these are simple log files.

Comment: Yeah they are all on same local network but there might be some cross datacenter file transfer as well. The files which I am transferring are memory-mapped files generated by Java program.

Comment: But I guess, that same pipe can handle three file transfer at a time, instead of one file transfer?

Comment: That's the trick with bandwidth: if you're filling the pipe to capacity with one file, doing three in parallel will take the same time at best but more likely slow the process down as the packets will cause collisions. I'm not a network guy, and there are more factors involved. It really depends on whether or not you're saturating the link.

Comment: Ignoring overhead, the best case time to send 400 * 3.5GB over 10Gbps is 18m40s. Even with compression and packet headers, 3 hours seems quite long. My guess is that the transfers are being throttled or the network is very busy already. Try running a test with several in parallel to see if the throughput improves.

Comment: Would using rsync here not be a much simpler solution? It would likely just handle the up-to-date detection of already existing files (those found on `machineB`) during the run against `machineC` and would allow for two ssh connections/command runs instead of 400. Just saw rsync mentioned in the OP. Which means try the parallel test that @DavidHarkness suggests. Also time how long simply creating 400+ ssh connections in your script takes without transferring any data to see what sort of overhead that has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already posted [another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/51168/12390) on this same topic two weeks later, with a better solution using GNU parallel.
I'll review this one too anyway on its own merit,
though it might be a bit of a moot point.

---

It's not a good idea to set `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` when using `ssh`.
The host key of servers should normally not change.
When they do, and you don't know why,
it might be a man in the middle attack.
If it's part of a scheduled server update,
you can manually update the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file accordingly.

---

When filtering the output of `ls` like this:

> ```
> ls -dt1 path | head -n1
> ```

you don't need the `-1` flag.
The purpose of that flag is to print the list of files in a single column.
But when you pipe the output to another command,
the output will be always a single column.

---

Instead of this:

> ```
> if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ]
> ```

This is easier (because you don't need to quote the variables) and more modern:

```
if [[ $dir1 = $dir2 ]]
```

---

Instead of cramming so many `ssh` options on the command line:

```
scp -o ControlMaster=auto -o 'ControlPath=~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p' -o ControlPersist=900 david@machineA:...
```

it's better to add these options in the `~/.ssh/config` file, like this:

```
Host machineA
Hostname machineA
User david
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/control-%r@%h:%p
ControlPersist 900
```

This way the `scp` command becomes simply:

```
scp machineA:...
```

---

I hope this (and even more, [my other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64448/12390)) helps!