# Copying into two different folders on a machine simultaneously

Tags: performance, file-system, bash, linux, concurrency

I am trying to copy files from `machineB` and `machineC` into `machineA` as I am running my shell script on `machineA`.

If the files are not in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC` for sure. I will try copying the files from `machineB` first, and if it is not in `machineB`, then I will try copying the same files from `machineC`.

I am copying the files in parallel using GNU parallel library and it is working fine. I am currently copying two files in parallel.

Earlier, I was copying the `PRIMARY_PARTITION` files in `PRIMARY` folder using GNU parallel and once that was done. I was then copying the `SECONDARY_PARTITION` files in the `SECONDARY` folder using same GNU parallel so it is sequential as of now with regards to the `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` folders.

Now I decided to copy files in `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` folder simultaneously.

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/test01/primary
export SECONDARY=/test02/secondary
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
export FILERS_LOCATION_1=${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}
export FILERS_LOCATION_2=${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(550 274 2 546 278) # this will have more file numbers
SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1643 1103 1372 1096 1369 1568) # this will have more file numbers

export dir3=/testing/snapshot/20140103

do_Copy() {
  el=$1
  PRIMSEC=$2
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMSEC/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMSEC/.
}
export -f do_Copy

parallel --retries 10 -j 5 do_Copy {} $PRIMARY ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}" &
parallel --retries 10 -j 5 do_Copy {} $SECONDARY ::: "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}" &
wait

echo "All files copied."
```

The script is working fine for me, but I am trying to see is there any better way of doing the same thing using GNU Parallel instead of using `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to see is there any better way of doing the same thing using GNU Parallel instead of using `&`.

Essentially you have two different commands and two different parameter lists:

1. Copy to PRIMARY, these files: 550 274 2 546 278
2. Copy to SECONDARY, these files: 1643 1103 1372 1096 1369 1568

These are two file-sets, two distinct operations. I don't think there's an easy way to do this with a single `parallel` process. A not-so-easy way can be:
organize the inputs in pairs, like this:

```
parallel -N2 do_Copy {1} {2} ::: 550 $PRIMARY 274 $PRIMARY 1643 $SECONDARY  # and so on
```

This way it will work with one command.
But constructing the argument list dynamically from your list of filenames will be tricky and potentially error prone.
The original solution is simple and easier to understand,
which are preferable properties.

#### Exporting variables

You don't need to export `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY`.

You only need to export `FILERS_LOCATION_1` and `FILERS_LOCATION_2`,
because these will be used by `do_Copy`,
which will be called by `parallel` (and also needs to be exported, as you correctly did).

Notice that the read-only `FILERS_LOCATION` array is pointless.
You could just as well set the `FILERS_LOCATION_*` variables directly:

```
export FILERS_LOCATION_1=machineB
export FILERS_LOCATION_2=machineC
```

#### Improving `do_Copy`

In this method,
you have two `scp` commands that are almost duplicates,
except the destination part.
To avoid the duplication,
you could just loop over the possible destinations,
and break out of the loop as soon as a copy was successful:

```
do_Copy() {
  el=$1
  PRIMSEC=$2
  for host in $FILERS_LOCATION_1 $FILERS_LOCATION_2; do
      echo "scp david@$host:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMSEC/." && break
  done
}
```

If the destination files might be exactly the same as the local files,
then you'll be better off using `rsync -u` instead of `scp`,
to avoid unnecessary file transfers.